# HP Victus AMD - Unable to start from suspend on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, hp, amd-graphics

I have not been able to start Ubuntu 22.04 after setting it to Suspend. When I try to resume it, the screen turns black. I cannot use the `nouveau` technique as I do not have an nvidia graphics card (I have an AMD RX 5500M/Radeon integrated graphics). What other information do I need to provide and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling Ubuntu. Attempting to install `amdgpu` pro drivers seemed to cause this issue.